# Refer to variable in loop when arranging rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to arrange rows in a dataset based on the year column in a second dataset. Since the column names that need arranging will be indexed from a vector, how can I enter them as an argument in the arrange function?

Note that I cannot simply order year in the first dataset as the full example has varied columns that need ordering.

```
data <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
  year=rep(c(2010, 2011), 5),
  employ=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", NA, "yes", "no", NA))

data2 <- data.frame(
 id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
 year=c(2010,2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011),
 employ=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", NA, "yes", "no", NA))

columns <- "employ"
```

Attempt:

```
for(i in seq_along(columns)) {data %>% arrange(as.name(columns[i]), data2[2])}
```

Desired output:

```
   id year employ 
1   1 2010    yes     
2   2 2010     no      
3   3 2010    yes     
4   4 2010   <NA>    
5   5 2010     no      
6   1 2011    yes     
7   2 2011    yes     
8   3 2011     no     
9   4 2011    yes     
10  5 2011   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrange` with `match` :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% arrange(match(year, unique(data2$year)))

#   id year employ
#1   1 2010    yes
#2   2 2010     no
#3   3 2010    yes
#4   4 2010   <NA>
#5   5 2010     no
#6   1 2011    yes
#7   2 2011    yes
#8   3 2011     no
#9   4 2011    yes
#10  5 2011   <NA>
```

In base R :

```
data[order(match(data$year, unique(data2$year))), ]
```

Comment: Can you please include a solution that uses the for loop?

Comment: How exactly do you think `for` loop can be used here?

Comment: The real example has many columns so I need arrange to look as follows arrange(columns[i], data2[2]). For example, I may have columns <- c("income", "employ", "gender")

Comment: In your example you have `columns <- "employ"` .How exactly is `columns` used here? I thought you want the answer based on the order present in `data2[2]` only. How is `employ` column related?

Comment: In the real example, data2 will get initialized with each new variable columns[i] and data[2] will be the same column at data[, columns[i]] but with a different order. I'm trying to get  data[, columns[i]]  to match the order of data[2]. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to use columns[i] as an input to arrange. I'm leaving out the full example because it's long but can include it if needed.

Comment: I still don't understand, yes maybe an example where usage of `columns` is actually relevant in the output would help. You can use `.data[[columns[i]]]` though in `arrange`.

Comment: You were right. I meant to write columns <- "year". Thank you for the solution .data[[columns[i]]]

Comment: For every column do you need separate datasets as output because when you are using `for` loop it is will first arrange the data by `.data[[columns[1]]]`, then by `.data[[columns[2]]]` so arrangement by `.data[[columns[1]]]` will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `factor`

```
data[order(factor(data$year, levels = unique(data2$year))),]
```

---

Or with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    arrange(factor(year, levels = unique(data2$year)))
#   id year employ
#1   1 2010    yes
#2   2 2010     no
#3   3 2010    yes
#4   4 2010   <NA>
#5   5 2010     no
#6   1 2011    yes
#7   2 2011    yes
#8   3 2011     no
#9   4 2011    yes
#10  5 2011   <NA>
```